# Error while building project : Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dependencies, android-appcompat

I'm trying to keep my current SDK version as 27 and don't want to upgrade to AndroidX. What can be the solution for this error?

[Error highlihted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNkwq.png)

Answer (score 0):

This issue, is because of partial AndroidX implementation.

Seeing the dependency you already are doing androidx partially, see the code

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
```

Either change the dependency from AndroidX to old one like

```
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0'
```

by following the guide over here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings

Which is basically, find the implementation you have in your build.gradle and finding it over there in table, and copy pasting the one on left side.

Or go to Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX and convert whole code to AndroidX.